# Windows Server 2012 R2 and Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, visual-studio

So I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Community on my Windows Server 2012 R2 box which will end up being a Jenkins build server. Attempting to do so gives an error saying that I need to install KB 2919355.

[image: Visual Studio error]

So I attempt to download the right KB from the [Microsoft download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42334). The two files that I would assume to work are either Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.msu and Windows8.1-KB2919355-x86.msu (just to try) and neither update work, saying that the update is not applicable.

[image: Installer error]

I've not been able to get this working and I haven't been able to find a proper way to fix this. Can anyone offer any suggestions or solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**These KB's must be installed in the following order**: *clearcompressionflag.exe, KB2919355, KB2932046, KB2959977, KB2937592, KB2938439, and KB2934018.*

**KB2919442** is a *prerequisite* for Windows Server 2012 R2 Update and should be installed before attempting to install KB2919355

Comment: I am having the same error "The update is not applicable to your computer." for KB2919442. Are there any pre-requisites for this? I'm having the same issue as the OP trying to get Visual Studio 2015 installed on Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install KB2919442(x86 or x64 based on your platform), and that's it.... now you can install KB2919355 and finally you can get visual studio 2015 installed on your system...